# Add Control To Bootstrap Pagination For Rows Per Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

The bootstrap pagination control doesn't appear to have an option to set the number of rows per page on the UI.

I have seen lots of pagination controls based on bootstrap but very few have this option.

[bs_pagination](https://github.com/pontikis/bs_pagination) comes close, however, it seems to just be a fixed value in the settings rather than an array.
[image]

[jeasyui](http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/pagination.php) can do it but the license is not compatible with my project and it has a style of its own.
[image]

Something like [Angular UI Pagination](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/pagination) would fit well with the project but I don't know how to handle the missing "rows per page" component.

Is there something pre-built for what I want?
If not, how would I go about adding it to an existing control?

EDIT: I have tried adding a control to the Angular UI component using Bootstrap input groups but I end up with a really wide select box with massive amounts of padding in the grouped control.
http://plnkr.co/edit/k1ZXOBZPAfp8Nb1kLKn6?p=preview

```
<div class="input-group"> 
<span class="input-group-addon">
  <uib-pagination total-items="bigTotalItems" ng-model="bigCurrentPage" max-size="maxSize" boundary-links="true" rotate="true" num-pages="numPages" previous-text="&lsaquo;" next-text="&rsaquo;" first-text="&laquo;" last-text="&raquo;"></uib-pagination>
</span>
 <span class="input-group-addon">
  <select id="numbers" class="form-control">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
  </select>
</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following link . [UI Bootsrap pagination demo](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/pagination)

And also the new codes have been changed and I think there's a problem with them. You can use following codes and also import my specific version. Then you can use it without errors.

```
<pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" ng-show="showPagination"
                                        ng-change="pageChanged()"></pagination>
```

In here, i use ng-show to hide the pagination until data is loaded. And also totalItems are loaded from the server and also you ca hard code that. And also pageChanged() is the following function and you can change that as you want.

```
$scope.pageChanged = function () {
    console.log($scope.currentPage);
    var number = parseInt(00);
    number = parseInt($scope.currentPage);
    if (number === 1) {
        number = 0;
    } else {
        number = (number - 1) * 10;
    }
    console.log("OFFSET IS : ,", number);
    getData($scope.loan.branch, $scope.loan.center, $scope.loan.fromDate, $scope.loan.toDate, number);
};
```

And use the following script to load angular ui setup.

```
<script src="lib/js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Use this js file and you can get that from early versions of ui bootstrap. 100% working for me.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I don't see how that adds the rows per page control though. I have added a plunkr to the question to demonstrate further what I mean.